# Understanding record from Ifta in 1640, during the 30-years war

Tags: german-language, transcriptions, kurrent, german, 30-years-war

I'm currently working on my ancestors from Ifta.  I'm trying to understand this church entry from 1640.  The [German Wikipedia's entry for Wolfmannsgehau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfmannsgehau) is the only reference I've been able to find which seems relevant to the specific events in this area at this specific time, though it doesn't cite any source for the information:

> During the Thirty Years' War, Croats camped below the Entenberg in the Croatian Trench ; They spread fear and terror on their raids in the Ringgau in 1637. In 1640 there were 30 abandoned (desert) farms in Ifta; only a twelfth of the agricultural land was still usable; In Wolfmannsgehau the four farms had burned down, all the men were dead and their survivors moved to neighboring towns.

The prior entry in the church book is from 30 Mar 1640, and the following entry, visible in this image, is from 2 Jun 1640.  I would appreciate any assistance completing the transcription of this entry.

[image: Ifta Kirchenbuch 1619-1672]

```
A zu Wolfmannsgehau zu [?] in die nacht gete...
sofin die kindlerein geflohn, als die cot...
[?] [?] auhgeglundert viell die pfarrkunder [?]
[?] gefeng nahr [?tung] gefurt, als
1. Heintz Wagman
2. Henrich Schwarzen - und seine beyde sohne, [Cyriacus?]
3. und Heinrich.
4
5 Hanß Spir[?] in der Benegessen
7. Belthasar Witland
8.9. Hanß und Adam Gotschellen
10. Heinrich Hast
11 Hanß Schwanz
12 Hanß Hartmann
13. Georg Jacob
16. Ludwig Solman
17. Cunrad Spor
18.19. Cunrad und Hanß Gesten, gebender.
20. Simon Burkhar
21. 22. sich die Pastorem selbste und mein hibt
sohelin Johann Wilhelm, [?eptennen].
23.24. Dorothea und Catharina, Casp Schwergen
p.m. tochter
25. Jacob Tahaufen. 26. Curt Hartmans p.m. [?]
filia
 

left sidebar:
[?] Jager sohn. Georg
--- [?]
ist zu [?] in
[?] [?] getauften
--- [?]
```

Note: I've also asked a variation on this question at the [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/74328/understanding-record-from-ifta-in-1640-during-the-30-years-war)